# How to design a linear GUI program

Tags: user-interface, qt

I'm making a simple Qt application. It has 4 screens/pages:

1. Start import
2. Select folder to import images to
3. Accept or reject each image in folder, and when no images left:
4. "No images left" and an OK button.

I can't figure out the best way to implement this. I started off with a QWidget, but this quickly got unmanageable.

Is a QWizard too constrained?

EDIT: Part of the problem with QWizard is it seems to always have "Back" and "Next" buttons. I don't want those as options in this program, so this leads me to believe that a wizard isn't exactly what I'm after.

Comment: Why can't there be a back button? What if I find out on screen 2 that I forgot an image on screen 1? Do I have to exit the wizard and start over?

Comment: I wasn't completely clear - I've changed the question slightly. Every time the user accepts or rejects an image, it copied to an accepted or rejected folder, then gets deleted from the device the images are being imported from. "Back" just doesn't make sense. The user has to accept or reject every image, so forward doesn't make sense either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to disagree slightly on using a `QWizard` here.  It would be fairly easy to do, but in this case I think it might be easier to just use a `QStackedWidget` and swap the widget shown based on what you want the user to be able to do.  This is likely what is done inside `QWizard` anyway, without some of the complication for running the buttons and moving back and forth.  You also might want to take a look at the state machine stuff they're looking at adding soon, since you're application could so easily be split into states.

Comment: I think this is more what I was thinking - I couldn't work out how the QWizard was doing it, but now I see!

Answer (score 5):

I think a QWizardPage is your best bet.

You can disable the 'back' on a QWizardPage by using `setCommitPage(True)` on it.

You'll also have to override `nextId` for the 'variable' amount of QWizardPages you want in between step 2 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/dialogs-trivialwizard.html) (basic) and [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/dialogs-classwizard.html) are examples of QWizards.

You can make QWizardPages for your screens and add them to a QWizard. With [registerField](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qwizard.html#registering-and-using-fields)() you can register fields to communicate between pages.

EDIT:
I didn't test this, but i guess you can control the button layout of QWizard with
[setButtonLayout](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qwizard.html#setButtonLayout)

Answer (score 0):

Create a dialog with a "Start Import" button on top.  When the user clicks this:

Populate a [`QFormLayout`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qformlayout.html) :

The layout should have a checkbox and the label is the name of the picture to import.  I'm not sure of your requirements, but you could also display a thumbnail of the image.

The user just checks the images he wants.

Then at the bottom have a "Save..." button.  When the user clicks this, a Save As dialog appears.  You save all the checked images, discard the others.

If there are no images, change the "Save..." button text to "OK", and display a `QLabel` with the "No images left" string.  You can switch between the `QLabel` and `QFormLayout` using a [`QStackedWidget`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qstackedwidget.html).

Checkout this article on `QFormLayout`: http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq25-formlayout.html

Option: Get rid of the "Start Import" button.  Have the app automatically populate the QFormLayout on startup (possibly in constructor if its fast enough).